Error Float value 501900 was truncated converting to int64
Estoy cargando archivos con extension .parquet pero al cargarlos me genera el error
Float value 501900 was truncated converting to int64

intente corregirlo de la siguiente manera
def dectx_toint(row):
    return row.fillna("0,0").str.replace(",", ".").astype(float).astype(int)

pero aun me genera error y redondeandolo a max y min pero no cambia el error

Hola, estaría bien que agregaras la traza completa del error y no solo éste, para ver de donde viene exactamente. Las versiones de pandas, numpy y pyarrow (si lo estas usando) serian también de ayuda y por ultimo si pudieras aportar un [mcve] ya sería fantástico. ¿El error se produce al leer el archivo o posteriormente al intentar cambiar el tipo? ¿Usas Arrow como dtype backend para el df? El error me hace pensar que puede estar implicado pyarrow, pero sin la traza y sin poder reproducir el error es difícil dar con la causa concreta en tu caso.
